# Why do we use Multiple dot notations in swift

Tags: swift, syntax

I have following swift code:

```
import UIKit

struct Foo{
    let bar = Bar()
}

struct Bar {
    let bas = Bas()
}

struct Bas {
    func sayHello(){
        print("hello")
    }
}

let foo = Foo()
foo.bar.bas.sayHello()
```

What is the point of declaring objects of one class into another class i.e Why to use `foo.bar.bas.sayHello()` where I can simply write `bas.sayHello()`?

Comment: `foo.bar.bas` and `bas` are two different instances of `Bas`

Comment: This is same as you use multiple square brackets in `Objective-C` `[[[foo bar] bas] sayHello];`. For calling further variables/functions.

Comment: Why don't I simply create object of `Bas` and call its methods directly ?

Comment: If you make a class `A` then declare a `B` class instance in it then declare `Bas` class instance into `B` class so both are different that you call `Bas`'s function by making its new instance or by `B`'s `Bas` instance. And if you can call `sayHello()` directly from `Bas` so this is your mistake that you are calling it like `foo.bar.bas.sayHello()`

Comment: Thank you @TheTiger . Can you tell what is the advantage of this object hierarchy i.e creating object of one class into another class

Comment: There is no advantage if you are not following a model. But if you have a model like `Student ---> Profile ---> Roll No., Name, Father Name, Class` then it makes easy to understand what code actually does and looks good.

Comment: In basic example: If you call a function `address()` nobody have any idea what kind of address is this. But if it were like `friend.homeInfo.address()` so it clearly says that this will call friend's home address.

Comment: Thank you @TheTiger Now its clear why do we use it.

Answer (score 0):

`foo.bar.bas` and `bas` are two different instances of `Bas`. With a small modification this is easier to observe:

```
struct Foo{
    let bar = Bar()
}

struct Bar {
    let bas = Bas(name: "Jeremy")
}

struct Bas {
    let name: String
    func sayHello(){
        print("hello \(name)")
    }
}

let foo = Foo()
foo.bar.bas.sayHello() // hello Jeremy

let bas = Bas(name: "Agatha")
bas.sayHello() // hello Agatha
```

Comment: What is the advantage of declaring object of one structure to another ??

Comment: You have an object graph… like `user.profileInformation.firstName` to get a user's first name. This lets you organize information.

Comment: Thank you @Aaron Brager . Can you please mention any link to learn the basics of my question ?